# Angular mousemove event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made a directive, inside I am attempting to listen to the $document.mousemove event in order to reposition a div - for the purpose of making a number slider (i.e. slide numbers between 1-100).

```
<div ng-mousedown="handleDown($event)"></div>
```

The above mousedown event is fired and handled by the following function:

```
$scope.handleDown = function(event) {
    console.log("MOUSE DOWN");
    event.preventDefault();
    startX = event.pageX - x;
    startY = event.pageY - y;
    $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
    $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
};
```

The mouseup function does work and causes a console log, but the mousemove does not fire at all:

```
function mousemove(event) {
    console.log("MOUSE MOVE");
}

function mouseup() {
    console.log("MOUSE UP");
    $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
    $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
}
```

If it is relevant, my directive:

```
.directive('fmSlider', function($document) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fmMin: '=',
            fmMax: '=',
            fmDefault: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'path-to-template/slider.html'
    };

});
```

I don't understand why the mouseup would work, but the mousemove would not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using `document.onmousemove` instead, works for me

Comment: There is something else going on outside of the code you provided. Here is a fiddle showing your code works fine. The mousemove event is firing.If that doesn't help, replicate your issue in a fiddle or share some more code

http://jsfiddle.net/G9jGa/17/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you but i encountered a similar problem with my code and my controller declaration looked first something like this

```
app.controller('ToolBoxCtrl', function ($scope)
```

but when i changed it to

```
app.controller('ToolBoxCtrl', function ($scope,$document)
```

then it worked. I am not quite sure why but hey at least something.

*Thanks to the example by Charlie Martin*

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **Event Listener**, like this:

```js
var variable = document.getElementById("mousedown");

variable.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
alert('test')});
```

```html
<div id="mousedown">
  On Mouse Down
</div>
```